# Free Mac scanning software (preferably to pdf)

Tags: mac, pdf, scanning

Does it exist? There are some great options in Linux using gscan, so it seems like it should make it's way to Mac, too. But after searching and searching, I can't find anything.
Thanks!

Comment: And I guess b/c Preview.app does it so well, there are no other free/simple alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's built-in in, for example, Preview. Connect the scanner and choose menu File, Import from scanner. Next, save as PDF.

(This does not do OCR text recognition though, so the PDF won't be easily searched and it depends on the PDF reader whether you can select text while viewing. See [Simple, free OCR software (for OS X)?](https://superuser.com/questions/9916/simple-free-ocr-software-for-os-x))

Comment: Holy cow! Just when you consider yourself OS savvy! Thanks! And it has a lot more options than I expected.

Comment: Hmmm, @Richard, you *do* know about Preview's [annotation options](http://superuser.com/questions/13354/what-is-the-best-paint-like-program-for-mac-os-x/13362#13362)? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Most scanners will have a TWAIN driver, which then most image software can hook into.

As far as free software, I've used GIMP for this (and I've also used the bundled software).

Answer (score 1):

image capture is another easy way to scan right out of the box.